# Saving image from Google Earth Desktop for selected area and time

Tags: google-earth

I am trying to save images from Google Earth Desktop for a certain rectangular area defined by latitude and longitude limits for a given time. I found a single latitude, longitude, heading, and range in the "geprint" format file but not time. Can someone help me with how to select different areas and times in the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a high-res image out of Earth Pro, you can simply pan/zoom to the view you want, select the desired date/time with the historical imagery tool, and then use the image export functionality (on Windows: File menu > Save > Save Image) to add map options (title, legend, etc.), select the image size, and save it out as a JPG file.

But it sounds like you're trying to use another tool (geprint?) to do that. I'm not familiar with it, but sounds like it can automate the process of saving specific images, along with saving the corresponding georeferencing information.  If that tool does not provide an option to choose a date/time, then it will likely only allow you to use the default "best and/or latest" base imagery. You could try setting the historical imagery slider in Earth Pro to the desired date/time before using the tool, and see if it keeps the setting?

Also, please be sure to read the Terms Of Service before using a tool like that, since there are limitations on how you are allowed to use images saved out of Google's mapping products.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. Keeping setting the historical imagery slider is also not working.  A GEPrint (Google Earth Print) configuration file is used for saving geolocation data from Google Earth. I found it on the internet somewhere. These files have the option of changing the location coordinates. However, I am not able to work properly with this formatted file. Later, I found KML files are the best for it, so I've started working with it. KML files have many options, including changing time.

Comment: It is just for more information. We can save images in Google Earth in geprint format by just clicking on "save image" in Google Earth. Google Earth itself give option to save image in geprint file.